# Fast way to count occurrences of all values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
from string import ascii_uppercase

random.seed(100)

n = 1000000

# Create a bunch of factor data... throw some NaNs in there for good measure
data = {letter: [random.choice(list(ascii_uppercase) + [np.nan]) for _ in range(n)] for letter in ascii_uppercase}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to **quickly** count the global occurrence of each value in the set of all values in the dataframe.

This works:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter([v for c in df for v in df[c].fillna(-999)])
```

But is very slow:

```
%timeit Counter([v for c in df for v in df[c].fillna(-999)])
1 loop, best of 3: 4.12 s per loop
```

I thought this function might speed things up by using some of pandas's horsepower:

```
def quick_global_count(df, na_value=-999):
    df = df.fillna(na_value)
    # Get counts of each element for each column in the passed dataframe
    group_bys = {c: df.groupby(c).size() for c in df}
    # Stack each of the Series objects in `group_bys`... This is faster than reducing a bunch of dictionaries by keys
    stacked = pd.concat([v for k, v in group_bys.items()])
    # Call `reset_index()` to access the index column, which indicates the factor level for each column in dataframe
    # Then groupby and sum on that index to get global counts
    global_counts = stacked.reset_index().groupby('index').sum()
    return global_counts
```

It's definitely faster (75% of the time of the previous approach), but there must be something quicker...

```
%timeit quick_global_count(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 3.01 s per loop
```

The results of the above two approaches are identical (with a little modification of the results returned by `quick_global_count`):

```
dict(c) == quick_global_count(df).to_dict()[0]
True
```

What's a quicker way of counting global occurrences of values in a dataframe?

Comment: So, the data is always single character in uppercase or NaNs?

Comment: Yes, let's assume that for this exercise. If the approaches differ significantly between the data above and whatever data you have in mind, it's probably a worthwhile pursuit to provide both examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Well the NumPy trick would be to convert to numbers (that's where NumPy shines) and simply let `bincount` do the counting -

```
a = df.fillna('[').values.astype(str).view(np.uint8)
count = np.bincount(a.ravel())[65:-1]
```

This works for single characters. `np.bincount(a.ravel())` holds the count for all the characters.

**Approach #1S (super-charged)**

Previous approach had bottlenecks at the string conversion : `astype(str)`. Also, the `fillna()` was another show-stopper. More trickery was needed to super-charge it by getting around those bottlenecks. Now, `astype('S1')` could be used upfront to force everything to single character. So, single characters stay put, while the NaNs get reduced to just a single character `'n'`. This lets us skip `fillna`, as the count for `'n'` could be simply skipped later on with indexing.

Hence, the implementation would be -

```
def app1S(df):
    ar = df.values.astype('S1')
    a = ar.view(np.uint8)
    count = np.bincount(a.ravel())[65:65+26]
    return count
```

Timings on `pandas-0.20.3` and `numpy-1.13.3` -

```
In [3]: # Setup input
   ...: random.seed(100)
   ...: n = 1000000
   ...: data = {letter: [random.choice(list(ascii_uppercase) + 
   ...:         [np.nan]) for _ in range(n)] for letter in ascii_uppercase}
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   ...: 

# @Wen's soln
In [4]: %timeit df.melt().value.value_counts()
1 loop, best of 3: 2.5 s per loop

# @andrew_reece's soln
In [5]: %timeit df.apply(pd.value_counts).sum(axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.14 s per loop

# Super-charged one
In [6]: %timeit app1S(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 501 ms per loop
```

---

**Generic case**

We can also `np.unique` to cover for generic cases (data with more than single characters) -

```
unq, count = np.unique(df.fillna(-999), return_counts=1)
```

Comment: Less than a second on my machine! Nice.

Comment: @blacksite Edited a bit to remove the subtraction by 65. Hopefully should be faster now.

Answer (score 5):

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts).sum(axis=1)
```

Benchmarking:

```
# example data
N = 10000000
rownum = int(N/1000.)
colnum = int(N/10000.)

str_vals = ['A','B','C','D']
str_data = np.random.choice(str_vals, size=N).reshape(rownum, colnum)
str_df = pd.DataFrame(str_data)

num_vals = [1,2,3,4]
num_data = np.random.choice(num_vals, size=N).reshape(rownum, colnum)
num_df = pd.DataFrame(num_data)

num_df.shape 
# (10000, 1000)

%%timeit
num_df.apply(pd.value_counts).sum(axis=1)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 883 ms per loop

%%timeit
str_df.apply(pd.value_counts).sum(axis=1)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 2.76 s per loop
```

Comment: Please see above. I extended the dataframe by a factor of 100 (to 1,000,000 rows) to show the speed difference between the `Counter` approach and the function I wrote. Yours is quicker than the `Counter` try, for sure, but is a bit slower than the custom function.

Comment: Just convert strings to numbers before running - that's your main speed restraint.

Comment: Interesting... Why would there be a difference counting occurrences of numbers versus strings? Like counting 1 through 26 in integers versus '1', '2', ..., '26'...

Comment: Not sure. But see benchmarking above, about 3x speedup when using numerical representation on reasonably big dfs.  Still, I'd say Divakar's answer looks faster.

Comment: Think that should be : `df.apply(pd.value_counts).sum(axis=1)`?

Comment: Awesome, this seems to be faster than my NumPy one! The string conversion in that one seems to be the bottleneck.

Comment: Nah, I improved a bit more. So, not slower anymore :)

Answer (score 4):

`melt` then `value_counts`(PS, still can not be compared with `numpy` solution )

```
 df.melt().value.value_counts()
```

---

Time

```
%timeit df.melt().value.value_counts()
100 loops, best of 3: 1.43 ms per loop
%timeit c = Counter([v for c in df for v in df[c].fillna(-999)])
100 loops, best of 3: 5.23 ms per loop
%timeit df.apply(pd.value_counts).sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 18.5 ms per loop
```